# Parse Oracle SQL in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle, oracle10g

Is there anyway to parse Oracle sql in .Net?
I have a small project with some tool that can execute some query to database to retrieve data, and i want to parse query to understand what query are (query or nonquery etc)

Any idea for this ? :)

Comment: you want to parse SQL query to understand what?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse oracle sql"?

Comment: i mean oracle statements... and to understand what type of query is (select or update or create table...). What if my query is multiple statements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing SQL in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083/parsing-sql-in-net)

Comment: But this is Oracle sql, not general SQL lol

Comment: not sure "to understand what query are" means, but try looking into DBMS_SQL package in Oracle to do your dirty work ;-)  Wrap in a procedure or function that returns the info you're looking for.

Comment: use system.data.oraclecilent library

Comment: why is this tagged tsql?

Comment: The linked Question does answer the oracle specific question as well, in the answers.